# Node.js + Express.js + serve-index: How to show all files in one view?

Tags: html, node.js, express, directory, auto-generate

I'm using expressjs/serve-index 
(https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index)
to generate an html file showing the contents of a directory on my server.  However, serve-index only shows one level at a time, and you have to click through the directory levels to see all the files.  Is there a setting to display all the files at once in a tree view?